# Android Image Asset is not drawn

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I am trying to implement a splash screen for my application, following the usual method; defining a new theme inside the styles XML file that places a drawable as windowBackground and reverting to the main theme in the Activity's onCreate().

However, I am having problems when showing the logo I developed in Photoshop: I exported it as a 144x144 PNG file, created an Image Asset with it (replacing the standard ic_launcher drawable) but when I try to visualize it inside an XML file, this image is displayed instead

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktTvo.png)

Any ideas? I've also tried to create a vector asset from the .psd but nothing is shown either...

Comment: Try moving the image out of mipmap and into drawable, then reference it in your xml as @drawable/your_image

Comment: Still the exact same problem :(

Comment: Try to determine if its your image of the layer-list, replace the bitmap image with another one and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

use this link to generate your icon. It will work.

Comment: Thank you! Thought this wasnt's what I was looking for, but did the job quite well :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the code and so on

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/your_background"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_image">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```